# Quarkus - Modify property during build time

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-extension

I'm trying to write my first extension and I'm trying to understand if there's a way for a Quarkus extension to modify build-time properties?
(i.e [`quarkus.otel.propagators`](https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry#quarkus-opentelemetry_quarkus-otel-propagators))

The idea is to create an extension which will provide several defaults specific to our environment, i.e among other things it will provide a propagator and any app that imports that extension should automatically enable that propagator if otel is enabled.

I was looking at [`ConfigurationBuildItem`](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/core/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/deployment/builditem/ConfigurationBuildItem.java) but this item provides read-only access to the config map.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, but I would first try adding `deployment/src/main/resources/application.properties`